# flutter embedding - Upgrading Pre 1.12 Android Projects Breaks Plugins

Tags: android, flutter

While building my flutter project, I was forced to follow the instructions in this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects for my shared_preferences package to work.
I followed the instructions there. Now my plugins seem to not work. for example signing with google throws this error: error MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in)

Similar errors happen with almost all of my plugins.

here is my flutter doctor -v logs

````
    • Flutter version 1.10.15-pre.404 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 9093cf15f6 (2 hours ago), 2019-11-04 22:30:16 -0500
    • Engine revision 7b968ff95f
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ajmal Jalal\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 41.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Ajmal Jalal\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category. ```
````

Comment: Right. For posterity, that was a bug in the framework. Sorry about that. Things should be fixed on version 1.12.

Answer (score -1):

This question was answered here in flutter's github page, and the answer there resolved my issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44161